# SceneKit- Cannot query using bitmask

Tags: swift, scenekit, virtual-reality, raycasting, realitykit

We were able to have custom raycasting using bitmasks:

```
let hitTest = sceneView.hitTest(location, options: [categoryBitMask: bitmask])
```

But hitTest is deprecated now and I can't figure out how to set bitmask for raycast query:

```
let query = sceneView.raycastQuery(from: location, allowing: .estimatedPlane, alignment: .horizontal)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### SceneKit

In SceneKit you can use bitmasks in context of  [SCNHitTestResult]. `hitTest(_:options:)` instance method is not deprecated yet and it works in iOS 15.4.

```
let sceneView = ARSCNView(frame: .zero)

enum HitTestType: Int {
    case object_A = 0b00000001
    case object_B = 0b00000010
}

let point: CGPoint = gesture.location(in: self.sceneView)

let bitMask = HitTestType.object_A.rawValue | HitTestType.object_B.rawValue

let results = sceneView.hitTest(point, options: [.categoryBitMask: bitMask])
```

P.S.

Only [hitTest(_:types:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arframe/2875718-hittest) is deprecated at the moment.

### RealityKit

In RealityKit you can use bitmasks in CollisionCastHit's context:

```
let arView = ARView(frame: .zero)

let point: CGPoint = gesture.location(in: self.arView)
    
let (origin, direction) = arView.ray(through: point)!
    
let raycasts: [CollisionCastHit] = arView.scene.raycast(origin: origin, 
                                                     direction: direction, 
                                                        length: 50, 
                                                         query: .any, 
                                                          mask: .default, 
                                                    relativeTo: nil)
```

...or this way:

```
let raycasts: [CollisionCastHit]  = arView.hitTest(point, 
                                                   query: .any, 
                                                    mask: .default)
```

Comment: Thanks @Andy but I think you are using RealityKit, SCNScene not contains "raycast" method.

Comment: You are right, I got it wrong with: "func hitTest(_ point: CGPoint, 
       types: ARHitTestResult.ResultType) -> [ARHitTestResult]"