# RealityKit – Add force to Entity at specific point

Tags: swift, game-physics, arkit, realitykit

I have my entity which has also physics I check for it with the `if let` syntax:

```
if let scoot = scooter as? HasPhysics { ... }
```

this works as charm I am able to get the user tap by using `UITapGestureRecognizer` this is just the first iteration I would like to use the `swipe` or `pan` gestures ideally.

```
// I can get the location of the tap in the arView
let location =  sender.location(in: arView)

// I can use this three approaches both of them returns me the Entity not sure which to use though
let hittest = arView.hitTest(location)
let results = arView.raycast(from: location, allowing: .existingPlaneInfinite, alignment: .any)
let entity = arView.entity(at: location)
```

At this stage I am in need of applying the force at the point of the Tap impact. Since I am in this iteration using tap, the force is always the same (in the next iteration I want to count with the velocity/vector of the impact and push my object with greater force on greater velocity gesture).

I just want to make sure the object is behaving the right way. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need the following approach.

First of all, apply `generateCollisionShapes(...)` instance method that  activates collisions for given entities.

```
func generateCollisionShapes(recursive: Bool)
```

Secondly, use `ray(...)` method returning an optional [tuple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70410251/scenekit-cannot-query-using-bitmask/70410675#70410675):

```
@MainActor func ray(through screenPoint: CGPoint) -> (origin: SIMD3<Float>, 
                                                   direction: SIMD3<Float>)?
```

Thirdly, use `arView.scene.raycast(...)` method that returns CollisionCastHit collection:

```
       func raycast(origin: SIMD3<Float>, 
                 direction: SIMD3<Float>, 
                    length: Float = 100, 
                     query: CollisionCastQueryType = .all, 
                      mask: CollisionGroup = .all, 
relativeTo referenceEntity: Entity? = nil) -> [CollisionCastHit]
```

Instance of `CollisionCastHit` can give you 4 subproperties:

```
CollisionCastHit().position
CollisionCastHit().entity
CollisionCastHit().distance
CollisionCastHit().normal
```

And at last, you already know the vector of force...

```
entity.physicsMotion?.linearVelocity = SIMD3<Float>()
```

Optionally, you might use an angular velocity of the body around the center of its mass.

```
entity.physicsMotion?.angularVelocity = SIMD3<Float>()
```

Comment: thank you and let me try it out, one quick question I have not used this `entity.physicsMotion?.linearVelocity` but something like this : 
```
entity.clearForcesAndTorques()
entity.addForce([0.0,-0.01,0.0], at:CollisionCastHit().position, relativeTo: nil)
```

will try out your approach and let you know. thank you!

Comment: There are always multiple solutions for the same task. ))

Comment: let me try the angular velocity as well :
this kind of works for me it is a bit of a mesh :
 `scoot.addForce([CollisionCastHit().normal.x, -2.0 * CollisionCastHit().normal.y, CollisionCastHit().normal.z], at:CollisionCastHit().position, relativeTo: nil)`