# RealityKit How to Get Two ModelEntities the same size in relation to each other?

Tags: swift, swiftui, realitykit, visionos

I'm creating text on the screen and would like there to be a 3d background like a 3D Plaque the text is on. I can place the text on the screen but I can't figure out how to get the box to appear with the same width and height and position of the text to be behind it. I'm assuming I should be able to set it to the same as the text and then it would be in the text and then I translate it a little bit back on the Z access and it will be behind it. Included is the code and an image of what I am getting. How can I make the purple box cover the text with the same width and height that can change dynamically depending on the text?

```
var body: some View {
        RealityView { content in
            let headAnchor = AnchorEntity(.head)
            headAnchor.anchoring.trackingMode = .once
            
            let model = GetText(testString)
            model.setParent(headAnchor)
            model.name = "test"
            model.transform.translation.z = -0.75
            model.transform.translation.y = -1.25
            model.transform.translation.x = -model.visualBounds(relativeTo: nil).extents.x / 2

            let blackBoxModel = ModelEntity(
                mesh: .generateBox(size: SIMD3<Float>(0.5,0.5,0.05), cornerRadius: 0.1),
                materials: [UnlitMaterial(color: .purple)])
            blackBoxModel.position = SIMD3<Float>(model.components[ModelComponent.self]!.mesh.bounds.max.x - model.components[ModelComponent.self]!.mesh.bounds.min.x, model.visualBounds(relativeTo: nil).extents.y, -0.75)
            blackBoxModel.setParent(headAnchor)
            content.add(headAnchor)
        }
}

func GetText(_ newText: String) -> ModelEntity {
        let depthVar: Float = 0.01
        let fontVar = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 0.1)
        let containerFrameVar = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 1, height: 1)
        let alignmentVar: CTTextAlignment = .center
        let lineBreakModeVar : CTLineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
        let model = ModelEntity(
            mesh: .generateText(newText, extrusionDepth: depthVar, font: fontVar, containerFrame: containerFrameVar, alignment: alignmentVar, lineBreakMode: lineBreakModeVar),
            materials: [SimpleMaterial(color: .white, isMetallic: true)])


        // Enable interactions on the entity.
        model.components.set(InputTargetComponent())
        model.generateCollisionShapes(recursive: false)
        model.components.set(HoverEffectComponent())
        
        return model
    }
```

[image: Realitykit image showing bounds]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code if you want to automatically calculate the size and position of the black box (text plate) based on the text location:

```
import SwiftUI
import RealityKit

struct ContentView: View {
    let sample = "This is the text on the screen"
    let mat = SimpleMaterial(color: .red, roughness: 0.7, isMetallic: true)
    let headAnchor = AnchorEntity(.head)

    init() {
        headAnchor.anchoring.trackingMode = .once
    }
    var body: some View {
        RealityView { content in
            // Text
            let textModel = await getText(sample)
            let xPos = textModel.visualBounds(relativeTo: nil).extents.x / 2
            textModel.position = [-xPos, -1.25, -0.75]
            textModel.setParent(headAnchor)
            // Text BB Center
            let bb_Center = textModel.visualBounds(relativeTo: nil).center
            let x = bb_Center.x
            let y = bb_Center.y
            let z = bb_Center.z
            // Text BB Extents
            let bb_Extents = textModel.visualBounds(relativeTo: nil).extents
            let xE = bb_Extents.x
            let yE = bb_Extents.y
            let zE = bb_Extents.z
            // Black box
            let blackBoxModel = ModelEntity(
                                        mesh: .generateBox(size: [xE+0.3, yE+0.2, zE],
                                cornerRadius: 0.1),
                                   materials: [UnlitMaterial(color: .black)]
            )
            blackBoxModel.position = [x, y-0.02, z-0.05]
            blackBoxModel.setParent(headAnchor)
            content.add(headAnchor)
        }
    }
    
    func getText(_ newText: String) async -> ModelEntity {
        let depthVar: Float = 0.01
        let fontVar = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 0.1)
        let containerFrameVar = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 1, height: 1)
        let alignmentVar: CTTextAlignment = .center
        let lineBreakModeVar : CTLineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
        
        let model: ModelEntity = await ModelEntity(
                                              mesh: .generateText(newText,
                                    extrusionDepth: depthVar,
                                              font: fontVar,
                                    containerFrame: containerFrameVar,
                                         alignment: alignmentVar,
                                     lineBreakMode: lineBreakModeVar),
                                         materials: [mat]
        )
        await model.components.set(InputTargetComponent())
        await model.generateCollisionShapes(recursive: false)
        await model.components.set(HoverEffectComponent())
        return model
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this! I changed the text to paragraphs and it still worked. Do you mind expanding on some things for me? Specifically, why are you taking the center of the text bounds for the position rather than feeding the black box position the text position? I'm thinking I don't know what transform means in RealityKit as to me matching the same position should be making it take the same space. Also does extents mean size like width and height? I'm just trying to figure out why you picked the things you did to make them work.

Comment: The idea behind this is quite simple: when you create a text model, its pivot point is located at lower left corner. To center (align) the text, we move it in the negative X direction. After that, we find the `central point` of the bounding box of the text along all three axes. This will be the starting point from which the black box plate will grow in three directions, using the `extents` parameter. And yes, extents is a XYZ size of a bounding box.

Comment: Ok so if I'm understanding this correct, the text model position starts at lower left and the box starts at center therefore boxes grow outwards from a center point while text grows out from a lower left point. Therefore we have to put the box in the center of the text to grow properly.

Comment: That's right. In Xcode Debug Visualizations menu, enable `Bounds` option to see the bounding boxes of both models.

Comment: Wow, I googled the debug visualizations as I didn't know what that was and tried it out and it is very helpful! Thank you very much!

Comment: By the way, in iOS RealityKit, debug options are part of ARView. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73287427/applying-downward-force-to-an-object-using-realitykit/73648884#73648884